# Age Verification Popup: Set cookie to remember decision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, remember-me

I am using the following code to display an age verification popup on a cigarette website:

```javascript
$(function() {
  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```js
// Popup Age Verification
$(function() {
  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
#popup {
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.verify-window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.verify-window img {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.verify-window h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.verify-window p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-align: center;
}

.button-yes,
.button-no {
    background: #fff;
    color: #ADCC21;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ADCC21;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.button-no {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #95969a;
    color: #95969a;
    display: block;
}

.button-yes {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.button-yes:hover {
    background: #ADCC21;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-no:hover {
    background: #95969a;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="verify-window">
        <h3>Age Verification</h3>
        <p>Are you at least 18 years old?</p>

        <div class="button-yes" data-popup-close="popup-1">
            Yes
        </div>

        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_parent">
            <div class="button-no">
                No
            </div>
        </a>
    </div><!-- // verify window -->
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Page Content</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

<sup>(Code source: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/xfk4m0xg/1/))</sup>

I want to implement a cookie that remembers when the user clicks on the `.button-yes` button. The other button shouldn't have a feature like this. How can I realize it the best way?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to add the cookie? This isn't a coding service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help. Please see [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Go on with https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie, and if not succeed ,  exapand your question here.

Comment: Possible off-topic here. This is a Q&A about programming, not about implementing your features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following implementation uses a `cookie` to store and retrieve the state of the age agreement. You should add a condition in `JavaScript` to identify the agreement state when the application starts. Also hide the `popup` by default using `css`.

CSS

```
#popup {
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

JavaScript using **Cookies**

```
$(function() {

  //Check it the user has been accpeted the agreement
  if (!(document.cookie && document.cookie == "accepted")) {
    $("#popup").show();
  }

  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    //Set a cookie to remember the state
    document.cookie = "accepted";

    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

JavaScript using **localStorage**

```
// Popup Age Verification

$(function() {

  //Check it the user has been accpeted the agreement
  if (!localStorage.getItem('accepted')) {
    $("#popup").show();
  }

  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    //Set a cookie to remember the state
    localStorage.setItem('accepted', true);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks good so far. But the popup shows again when I refresh the page.

Comment: Did you set `display: none;` in css for `#popup`. Otherwise it should set the cookie.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it still doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I updated the fiddle but every time I refresh my browser, the popup still seems to be there...

Comment: See the updated answer. I added the solution using `localStorage`. Since the code executes within an iFrame inside the jsFiddle, it may not reflect the exact behavior as a website. But both these methods are correct.

Comment: Using localStorage, there is no way to store the decision for 48 hours, right?

Comment: You can add another key with the time and do a time calculation to check the span of 48 hours.